# I have a chipGroup, I also created a custom style for the same

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

In the custom style, the background color is changing but only the font color isn't changing.

```
<style name="CustomChipStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter">
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor" >@color/chips_bg_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/chips_text_color</item>
        <item name="chipIconTint">@color/tomato_red</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? If you want the font color to change, you need to use `android:textColor` instead of `android:textColorHint` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style name="CustomChipStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor" >@color/chips_bg_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/chips_text_color</item>
    <item name="chipIconTint">@color/tomato_red</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/white</item>
```

You need to use android:textColor for changing your font color.